# (AS3) Two arrays associated? Change on one changes the other

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

When I splice an entry from my one array, it splices the same entry from my other array... What is happening?

```
        private static var words:Array = new WordFile().toString().split(/\n/);
        private static var wordsTemp:Array;

public static function checkWord (word:String):Boolean
    {
var truefalse:Boolean = wordsTemp.indexOf(word+"\r".toLowerCase()) > -1;
                trace (words.length)

                wordsTemp.splice(wordsTemp.indexOf(word+"\r".toLowerCase()), 1);

                trace (words.length)
   return truefalse

}
public static function resetArrays :void
{
wordsTemp = words
}
```

With this code, I call the resetArrays function every time a new game is started. Once in the game, the program will call checkWord with a word being passed to it. If it is found in the word array, it will splice it from the temporary array. However, when I run it, the 2 traces yield 2 different numbers, with the second one being one lower (assuming the word was found in the array). This seems to me to be very strange as I am splicing the temporary array that gets reset, however when tracing the array that is supposed to be unchanged (there is no operations other than the ones I am showing you with it in it) it seems to be changed by a splice in the temporary array...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In AS3, all data types except `String` and `Number` (and related) are copied **by reference**

This means that it only copies a reference to the original object when you use `myArray1 = myArray2`

In more detail, consider the memory at which `words` is stored is `0x123456`

`wordsTemp = words` will make `wordsTemp` point to the same memory, i.e. 0x123456

When you do any operation on `words`, the array at 0x123456 is modified. But this is what `wordsTemp` refers to. So in reality both are the same object. To make both different, you need to *clone* the object. In case of an array, you can clone it using any method that modifies the array and returns the new array, e.g. `Array.slice`

```
wordsTemp=words.slice(0, words.length); //will do the trick
```

Or, you could concatenate nothing to the original array and get a duplicate

```
wordsTemp=words.concat();
```

Alternatively, if you want to write more lines of code, here's what you can do:

```
wordsTemp=new Array();
for (var i:int=0; i<words.length; i++) {
    wordsTemp.push(words[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do wordsTemp = words, you don't just assign the array item, but the memory space in the program. You have to copy all item from the first array to the second, but not set it equal has you do.

You can do a loop to copy all item from words to wordsTemp or do something like :

```
wordsTemp = words.slice(0, words.length);
```

It will return a copy of the original array without modifying it
Hop that can help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the easiest and "standard" way to clone an array in AS3 is:

```
var cloneArray:Array = sourceArray.concat();
```